# Speed up "Find points in polygon"-query in geodjango

Tags: django, polygon, postgis, point, geodjango

I am working on a geodjango application where I want to find all the geogrpahic locations in a polygon. The idea is that I store all geographic information (cities, countries, POI, etc.) in a table and if I want to find everything inside a (multi)polygon that I query the database to find those points.

I have the following models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    geometry = models.GeometryField(null=True, blank=True)


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    location = models.ManyToManyField(Location, related_name='projects', blank=True)
```

In my view I have:
    class LocationDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Location

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        location_geometry = self.get_object().geometry

        location_projects = []
        if 'Polygon' in location_geometry.geom_type:
            # location is a Polygon or MultiPolygon
            for loc in Location.objects.prefetch_related('projects').all():
                if location_geometry.contains(loc.geometry):
                    for location_project in loc.projects.all():
                        location_projects.append({'name': location_project.name, 'pk': location_project.pk})

        # Add in a QuerySet of all the projects
        context['projects'] = location_projects
        return context
```

This is quite slow (and I do not have only a few hundred locations in the DB). As you can see I've tried speeding this up by prefetching the projects, but when I look at the SQL in the debug toolbar I see that (although it is a fast query) one query is duplicated 259 times:

```
SELECT
    "app_location"."id",
    "app_location"."name",
    "app_location"."geometry"::bytea,
FROM
    "app_location" WHERE "app_location"."id" = 979

Duplicated 259 times.
```

And this query is called once but is rather slow:

```
SELECT
    ("app_project_location"."location_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_location_id",
    "app_project"."id",
    "app_project"."name"
FROM
    "app_project" INNER JOIN "app_project_location" ON
    ("app_project"."id" = "app_project_location"."project_id")
WHERE "app_project_location"."location_id" IN (780, ..., 1018, 1019, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1023)
```

How would I be able to do this more efficiently? I could ofcourse load all the objects and do the point in poly part in python but I assume that it can be done in the DB directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jedndrusk his answer I looked around some more on the internet and found the solution which is much faster and in geodjango:

```
projects = []
if 'Polygon' in self.get_object().geometry.geom_type:
# location is a polygon
    for loc in Location.objects.filter(geometry__intersects=self.get_object().geometry).prefetch_related('projects').all():
        for project in loc.projects.all():
            projects.append({'name': project.name, 'pk': project.pk})
```

Comment: Could you provide some of the sources where you read about this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using postgresql and postgis (?) you can do this in database using query. PostGIS provides many spatial functions to do that:

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Covers.html

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html

To avoid performance issues take care about spatial indexes:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200222103516/http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html

Since I'm not a big fan of ORM I'm not sure how to do this in django model, but I'm quite sure it's possible

Comment: Yes I use a postgres + postgis DB. I will look in to those functions, although it would be nice to use it through the ORM of django though (it is maybe not as efficient as writing queries yourself, but it does increase development speed)